# add-to-ordered-list is not placing element at the alphabetic order

Tags: sorting

I am having an ordered list to which i am trying to add alphabets. But I see, the newly inserted element is placed out of order. This example is taken from [gnu manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html)

```
(setq foo '())
     ⇒ nil

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'a 1)     ;; Add a.
     ⇒ (a)

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'c 3)     ;; Add c.
     ⇒ (a c)

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'b 2)     ;; Add b.
     ⇒ (a b c)

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'b 4)     ;; Move b.
     ⇒ (a c b)

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'd)       ;; Append d.
     ⇒ (a c b d)

(add-to-ordered-list 'foo 'e)       ;; Add e.
     ⇒ (a c b e d)

foo                       ;; foo was changed.
     ⇒ (a c b e d)
```

As one can see in the penultimate statement, `e` is not inserted at the end as per the alphabetic order. Instead it is being placed before `d`.

Comment: Looks like the docstring of that function is not very informative, but its [description in the documentaion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#index-add_002dto_002dordered_002dlist) is.

Comment: Actually, now I see that you got your example from there. So read the description of the function again, and note the sentence that ends with 'in no particular order'.

Comment: The key to understanding this behaviour is knowing that `add-to-ordered-list` performs a full sort of the list.

Comment: (Minor FYI): No need to quote `nil`: `(setq foo '())`. `nil`, which is also `()`, evaluates to itself.